# All indices got deleted suddenly in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

We have an AWS Managed ES Cluster, and 4 indices in them. Our data was there in all the indices till 31st December, 2019. However, when we returned on **2nd Jan, 2020, we saw all the indices were deleted!** This is really terrifying for us. I quickly did a _cat/indices with creation time, and I noticed that the index **.kibana_1** had creation time at **31st December, 8:40 AM GMT** and one index had creation time at 31st December, 1 PM GMT. Some other indices were created after that time due to ingestion triggers from our product.

But that shouldn't be the case, **since our cluster was hosted 1-1.5 months before**. We never stopped the AWS ES Cluster from the point it was up. We tried to know the uptime of the cluster assuming any restart would have impacted the indices in any way but didn't find a way to see know the uptime of the cluster.

We have a **single node** and it's uptime is being shown as **3.8d (assuming 3.8 days)** as I ran the query just today. That's bringing even more confusion as our .kibana_1 index was created on December 31st, which is almost 5 days ago. Not completely sure if this is an expected scenario or not.

I didn't enable any access control on the cluster and only a couple of folks have access to the cluster and **none of them ran a delete request on the cluster**. We didn't enable any logging on the AWS Cluster. The total data in all the indices combined is less than 5 GB.

We did revert to a snapshot that we had on 31st December. But we did lose all the 2 days data. I really would like to know under what conditions something like this will happen. We are going to production with the whole product in a few weeks and assuming this can happen again is scaring me now.

Any thoughts and ideas of how this happened and how to prevent it from happening in future?

Comment: you should reach out to AWS Premium support folks

Comment: regarding prevention, you could restrict your cluster to disallow delete verbs. see - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html

Comment: @AshishModi Yes, we did consider that.